# Как из одного массива взять значения для трёх

Tags: java

Имеется массив `ArrayList` типа `String`, как брать из него 1 элемент для нового массива, второй элемент для второго нового массива, третий элемент для третьего нового массива, а дальше четвертый для первого и так далее? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно пройтись циклом и выбрать кратный индекс:

```
List<String> help_arr = new ArrayList<String>();

help_arr.add("a1");
help_arr.add("a2");
help_arr.add("a3");
help_arr.add("a4");
help_arr.add("a5");
help_arr.add("a6");

List<String> help_arr1 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> help_arr2 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> help_arr3 = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < help_arr.size(); i++) {
    if ((i + 3) % 3 == 0)
        help_arr1.add(help_arr.get(i));
    if ((i + 3) % 3 == 1)
        help_arr2.add(help_arr.get(i));
    if ((i + 3) % 3 == 2)
        help_arr3.add(help_arr.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот тебе универсальный сплиттер. Разложит любой список на любое количество списков. Писал на коленках и не проверил на работоспособность, но должно сработать

```
<T> List<List<T>> splitList(List<T> list, int splitCount) {
    List<List<T>> resultList = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
    for (int i = 0; i< splitCount; i++) {
        resultList.add(new ArrayList<T>());
    }
    int n = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        resultList.get(n++).add(list.get(i));
        if (n == splitCount) {
            n = 0;
        }
    }
    return resultList;
}
```